# do not want to save the response time by a http request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Scenario : 
Thread 
  HTTP Req 1 : Login
  HTTP Req 2 : Homepage 
  HTTP Req 3 : Logout

I want to execute all 3 requests while run, but doesn't want that response time/throughput time etc to be saved in Report for Login (but necessary to execute as that authenticate the user credentials).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment it is not possible, there is an [enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54333) to add this functionality since JMeter 2.6 but it hasn't been implemented yet so you can vote for it, it may trigger the implementation.

Also it looks like that the option may come with the next [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) release: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/_HRTcyZi1ek

Currently you can work it around by adding a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice to record KPIs only for samplers you need to monitor, like:

[image: Listener]

and use "Configure" button to choose what you need to record.

Also if you have hands on programming you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) and [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) to perform the login as Pre/PostProcessors and Timers duration isn't being recorded by default unless you use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) which explicitly "tells" JMeter to do so.